# client.await_for unresponsive In a Loop Under Cogs Folder | Discord.py

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py, setup.py

I made a number-guessing command in Discord.py. The command works perfectly fine outside of any cogs folder (main.py). Because my main.py was getting cluttered, I relocated the guess command into one of the cog's folders where I organized my other commands. When I ran the bot and try to use the guess command, I get an error saying:

```
loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hooktype
```

Below is the code I used for the guess command inside the cog:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def guess(self, ctx):
        try:
            await ctx.send(f"Pick a range of numbers you want and the number of attempts you want."
                           f"Ex: '__**1-10**, **4**__' or '__**600-10**, **200**__'")

            def check(msg):
                return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

            msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

            user_range = msg.content
            num = re.findall(r'\d+', user_range)  # get the values from the msg.content or user input
            range_1 = int(num[0])
            range_2 = int(num[1])
            attempt = int(num[2])

            if range_1 > range_2:
                range_1 = int(num[1])
                range_2 = int(num[0])
                await ctx.send(
                    f"Now guess a number between **{range_1}-{range_2}**, you have **{attempt}** attempts. Type 'stop' to give up.")

                def check(msg):
                    return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

                Entry = 0
                ran_picker = random.randrange(range_1, range_2)
                while Entry <= attempt:
                    msg = await client.await_for('message', check=check)
                    Entry = Entry + 1
                    if msg.content == "stop" or msg.content == "Stop":
                        await ctx.send(f"You gave up ")
                        await ctx.send(f"The number was **{ran_picker}**")
                        break
                    elif int(msg.content) == ran_picker:
                        await ctx.send(f"**Good job, it was {ran_picker}!**")
                        break
                    elif int(msg.content) > range_2 or int(msg.content) < range_1:
                        await ctx.send(f"Pick a number between **{range_1}-{range_2}**!")
                        Entry = Entry - 1
                        print(Entry)
                    elif Entry == attempt:
                        await ctx.send(f"You ran out of inputs, it was **{ran_picker}**!")
                        break
                    else:
                        await ctx.send(f"Nope, keep guessing", delete_after=2)
            else:
                await ctx.send(
                    f"Now guess a number between **{range_1}-{range_2}**, you have **{attempt}** attempts. Type 'stop' to give up.")

                def check(msg):
                    return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

                Entry = 0
                ran_picker = random.randrange(range_1, range_2)
                while Entry <= attempt:
                    msg = await client.await_for('message', check=check)
                    Entry = Entry + 1
                    if msg.content == "stop" or msg.content == "Stop":
                        await ctx.send(f"You gave up ")
                        await ctx.send(f"The number was **{ran_picker}**")
                        break
                    elif int(msg.content) == ran_picker:
                        await ctx.send(f"**Good job, it was {ran_picker}!**")
                        break
                    elif int(msg.content) > range_2 or int(msg.content) < range_1:
                        await ctx.send(f"Pick a number between **{range_1}-{range_2}**!")
                        Entry = Entry - 1
                        print(Entry)
                    elif Entry == attempt:
                        await ctx.send(f"You ran out of inputs, it was **{ran_picker}**!")
                        break
                    else:
                        await ctx.send(f"Nope, keep guessing", delete_after=2)
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"{error}")
            await ctx.send(f"Problem: **[{error}]**")re
```

In fact, other commands that's inside a cog folder involving the function/line

```
msg = await client.await_for('message', check=check)

# specifically' client.await_for'
```

I get a similar error.

I am fairly new to Python's language and Discord.py. I tried to read some of the documents for discord.py revolving around "setup_hooktype" and try to see how I can implement it into my code. Every time I change something I get a new error saying: "unexpected keyward argument," "no attributes" and so on. I believe this function has to do with the subclass (which I have for the cog) but I'm not sure how to create an addon for "setup_hook." I could just leave this command in my main.py, but soon or later I'm going to encounter this problem again in the future.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why are you using **a**wait_for instead of wait_for? Also, saying "I get an error" is not useful at all. Post the actual traceback and the setup_hook-code that you tried.

Comment: This error message also doesn't make too much sense if you're saying it comes from that line. Can we see the entire error?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "wait_for" not "await_for." Either way, I figured out the issue, all I needed to do was add "self" in front of "client.wait_for."